# Armadillo + VS 2015 - How to link with NVBLAS

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, armadillo, nvblas

as per title, is there an easy way to link Armadillo with NVBLAS in VS 2015?

At the moment I've installed MKL in VS, and everything is working flawlessly. I've installed CUDA Toolkit 8 with the extension in VS, can I somehow instruct Armadillo to take the (available) BLAS routines in CUDA?

Comment: I +1ed this question because I really am interested in learning this because I'll need it sometime in the future. Please put the answer when you have it. Also consider reading here: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nvblas/

Comment: Will do! Thanks for posting that link, I'll give another look to that. I was actually looking for something out of the box (as it was for MKL), and I'm sure there's a simple way to do that in VS